# Accept keyof of an object with a specific type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this type (shortened here for example):

```
type Form = {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    age: number
};
```

I want to create two functions, one which accepts any key of Form where the value is of type string, and one for number. So the first one should accept `"firstName" | "lastName"` and the second one `"age"`

I also want to be able to index the object with the key and get back the correct type. E.g. for the string function:

```
function stringKey<... magic ...>(form: Form, key: ...) {
  form[key] // should be of type string
}
```

I made a guess and tried this but it's invalid syntax. Is it possible to do this in TypeScript?

```
function stringKey<K extends keyof Form, Form[K] extends string>()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is totally possible

First of all you need to pick all props of corresponding type from object

```
type PickByType<OBJ extends object, VALUE_TYPE> = Pick<
  OBJ, 
  {
    [KEY in keyof OBJ]-?: OBJ[KEY] extends VALUE_TYPE
      ? KEY // Keep key/value pair if value is of VALUE_TYPE
      : never // Brush it off otherwise
  }[keyof OBJ] // Meaning we take every key/value pair from object above and combine them with union type
>
```

Once you have it, you need to pick all keys from this type, I think you are able to do it yourself :)

Resulting function you got almost right

Try to get to the answer yourself with this hint above. After that, feel free to [check out complete solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLZQLxQN4Cgq6gMwEsEBnYAOQEMkIAuKMhQgOwHMAaHPAG0rKpr1GLDl1yVWdKMwCuSAEYQEWAL4BuLFlCQoABUIBjANYAhEABVwEADwB5EwCkoEAB7AIzACYkoceQCsIA2B2KAA1AEEAGQBVAFEAfXMATV04gD40PUMjay57B1CubDwoAG0AaTjkqBYoIwgQOHwoAoBdAFoAfnoCyuq25zcPb3Do+KTUuLE8LqgqmoB6RfmICDB6xsWAN0puGWgwSmJalt396EIfZrHYxJS0mdx6ZghtpShlqBMEGRIAC1qwF8+BacGA-yUAHcrhAuCoyg0mi12p8VgBZCCUZgiKBQ6DASgNZzvBAgTYgHZ7A5QI4nfAIOAoPyBYJQSjyODvdleKAGJnyFgEyEoGEQqAyHFwZhQbRw9KaOVQADKwCYbAqjTsQ3cXmuASCwEy6CRN30xjMlkgdlCwjYCqw-OYZAIiCQ9HgyCyJTwRFIFGoUgA5A44P9mEHOKVePxA-QgwAROAQSMzCRSACMAGYAGyqDRYfCS4KEaUMNUiTUgbWuXWjFmG9IAChZvVCSPoqvVrCrdnSAEpMFwEBBgDIEDKWYjGm0NCpNF8lVdy93HdKXecaeg7T3Gk38G7QkG-bGaEH+0A)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. What is `-?:` though? I'm unable to search it on Google and also if I replace it with just `:`, the code still compiles.

Comment: It subtracts `-` the optional `?` status (may be omitted) from the property `{ a?: string }` -> `{ a: string }`. Since all properties here are not optional, it doesn't really have any effect in this case.

Answer (score 1):

First you need a way to get only the property names that are typed as string. You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to do that. Iterate over each key and find the ones that have `string` as their type.

```
type StringKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never
}[keyof T]

// Test it out
type FormPropertiesThatAreString = StringKeys<Form> // 'firstName' | 'lastName'
```

Now you can write your function with a single generic parameter for that key, constraining it to `StringKeys<Form>`.

```
function stringKey<K extends StringKeys<Form>>(form: Form, key: K) {
  const shouldBeAString: string = form[key] // type: string
  const shouldBeAnError: number = form[key] // type error
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLZQLxQN4Cgq6gMwEsEBnYAOQEMkIAuKMhQgOwHMAaHPAG0rKpr1GLDl1yVWdKMwCuSAEYQEWAL4BuLFlCQoAZWBM2AaQggSAHgAqAPjSYuAbSNQWUANam4+KJYC69SydfKAgAD2AIZgATEgYDESgAfihnemYIADclVQcPEC8fX01taABBO31DVhMzc3hka018GWYAY2BCOGY4qprzZzCI6NjKkRqLeqRrawAKfEQkekn2d1N6IwBKe1xWrrIGAAs4GW4ogCEIUtG2IXi2O3nkXNNggHpXqBLbqq5d5n2SEcTudLswAKIIBCINJyRQIB4LZ4gN4fEohSGIVRAA)